# how can i find and write a list even and odd numbers?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

A program that reads a sequence of numbers
and counts how many numbers are even and how many are odd. When numbers of even output maybe 4, then the list is show even numbers and odd number. i got error in my code, this is my code:

```
odd_numbers = 0
even_numbers = 0
lst_odd =[]
lst_even =[] 
# read the first number
number = int(input("Enter a number or type 0 to stop: "))

# 0 terminates execution
while number != 0:
# check if the number is odd
   if number % 2 == 1:
        # increase the odd_numbers counter
        odd_numbers += 1
        return lst_odd
   else:
    # increase the even_numbers counter
    even_numbers += 1
    return lst_even
    # read the next number
   number = int(input("Enter a number or type 0 to stop: "))


 # print results
 print("Odd numbers count:", odd_numbers, '\n','list odd numbers is', lst_odd)
 print("Even numbers count:", even_numbers, '\n','list odd numbers is',lst_even)
```

i want to make the out like that:

```
Enter a number or type 0 to stop:  3
Enter a number or type 0 to stop:  3
Enter a number or type 0 to stop:  4
Enter a number or type 0 to stop:  5
Enter a number or type 0 to stop:  6
Enter a number or type 0 to stop:  7
Enter a number or type 0 to stop:  8
Enter a number or type 0 to stop:  2
Enter a number or type 0 to stop:  4
Enter a number or type 0 to stop:  0
Odd numbers count: 4
list odd number is [3,3,5,7] 
Even numbers count: 5
list even number is [4,6,8,2,4]
```

Comment: What is the output from the code you have?

Comment: `return lst_odd` should be `lst_odd.append(number)` and the same for lst_even. - `return lst_even` should be `lst_even.append(number)`

Comment: You don't need counters. Learn the `len()` function

Answer (score 0):

When using `return`, you need code within a function. To add to a list, you `append` to it

For example

```
def main():
    lst_odd = []
    lst_even = [] 

    while True:
       number = input('Enter a number or "stop": ')
       if number.lower() == 'stop':
           return lst_odd, lst_even  # end the loop, return both lists
       n = int(number)
       if n % 2 == 1:
            lst_odd.append(n)
       else:
            lst_even.append(n)

odds, evens = main()
print('Odd numbers count: {}\nList odd numbers is {}'.format(len(odds), odds))
print('Even numbers count: {}\nList even numbers is {}'.format(len(evens), evens))
```